# How to fix 'Trying to get property of non-object' error in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Please help me to fix the error in laravel 5.4,  I Want to build table availability with this code.

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">#</th>
                    @for($tanggal=1; $tanggal<=14; $tanggal++)
                    <th scope="col">{{$tanggal}}</th>
                    <!-- str_pad($tanggal, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT) -->
                    @endfor
                </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
                @foreach($times as $time)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{$time}}</td>

                    @for($tanggal=1; $tanggal<=14; $tanggal++) 
                    <td scope="row">  
                            {{App\Bookreport::where('book_date','=', '2019-01-'.$tanggal)->where('book_time','=',$time)->first()->book_time}}
                    </td>

                    @endfor
                </tr>
                @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Error "Trying to get property of non-object"

In line

```
{{App\Bookreport::where('book_date','=', '2019-01-'.$tanggal)->where('book_time','=',$time)->first()->book_time}}
```

Comment: may be you are getting empty results for certain date or time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a simple solution to your problem is to change this:

```
{{App\Bookreport::where('book_date','=', '2019-01-'.$tanggal)->where('book_time','=',$time)->first()->book_time}}
```

To:

```
{{App\Bookreport::where('book_date','=', '2019-01-'.$tanggal)->where('book_time','=',$time)->first()->book_time ?? ''}}
```

---

But actually this is not the best solution!

a better way is to send your data from the controller to your view, so you query data in your controller and pass it to your view.
in your controller:

```
$from = date('2019-01-01');
$to = date('2019-01-14');

$books = App\Bookreport::whereBetween('book_date',[$from, $to])->whereIn('book_time',$times);

return view('some_view')->withBooks($books);
```

then in your view, just iterate over the `$books` variable and print the results.

P.S. this code is not tested, it may require some modifications.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Check this line

```
 {{App\Bookreport::where('book_date','=', '2019-01-'.$tanggal)->where('book_time','=',$time)->first()->book_time}}
```

when you are using `first()` then it does not return an `Std Class object`. If you want it so then use  `get()`

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
{{App\Bookreport::where('book_date','=', '2019-01-'.$tanggal)->where('book_time','=',$time)->first()->book_time}}
```

To

```
<?php 
$bookReport = App\Bookreport::where('book_date','=', '2019-01-'.$tanggal)->where('book_time','=',$time)->first();
?>
@if($bookReport!=null)
{{$bookReport->book_time}}
@else

@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">#</th>
                    @for($tanggal=1; $tanggal<=14; $tanggal++)
                    <th scope="col">{{$tanggal}}</th>
                    <!-- str_pad($tanggal, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT) -->
                    @endfor
                </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
                @foreach($times as $time)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{$time}}</td>

                    @for($tanggal=1; $tanggal<=14; $tanggal++) 
                    <td scope="row">  

<?php 
$bookReport = App\Bookreport::where('book_date','=', '2019-01-'.$tanggal)->where('book_time','=',$time)->first();
?>

{{$bookReport->book_time}}
                    </td>

                    @endfor
                </tr>
                @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Always when you are not sure about existing of record in database , you should use:

> count() or isEmpty()

and if it exists , get it by

> first()